# Is there a way to import images from a Wiki table into a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, mediawiki

I'm trying to import a MediaWiki table from here: https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_2021_Hot_Wheels

I want to be able to also pull the images, but when I use ImportHtml in sheets (like so: `=ImportHtml("https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_2021_Hot_Wheels", "table", 1)`), the "photos" column is just blank:
[image: a google spreadsheet displaying information about hot wheels. the photo column is blank.]

Is there anything I can do here? I would be alright if, at the very least, I could pull the link to the photo to put there if I can't pull the photos themselves.

Comment: Not sure if it helps your case, but it worthes mentioning that when retriving the HTML of a MediaWiki page, the [?action=render](https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_2021_Hot_Wheels?action=render) query parameter is useful for providing just the content HTML, without all the interface around.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX(IMAGE(QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1, "//a/@href"), 
 "where Col1 contains 'images'")))
```

[image]

to get whole table use:

```
=INDEX({SUBSTITUTE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 IMPORTHTML(A1, "table", 1),  9^9, 4), "*", ), 
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({"Photo"; IMAGE(QUERY(
 IMPORTXML(A1, "//a/@href"), 
 "where Col1 contains 'images'"))}, 448, 1)})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case IMPORTHTML can't access links or images that's why the images are not retrieved when calling the function, a solution could be that you call the image directly by using the [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333) function in Sheets. To do this however you will first need to limit the columns that you are retrieving from the table:

```
=QUERY(ImportHtml("https://hotwheels.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_2021_Hot_Wheels", "table", 1), "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5")
```

Then you will need to manually add the last column and import the image:

```
=IMAGE("https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/hotwheels/images/a/a9/GRX90_-_The_Nash.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20210812001135")
```