How can I add images from a table on a website into google sheets?
I am trying to import all of the images on this page:
https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Bestiary/Levels_1_to_10
into a google spreadsheet.
I've gotten as far as
=IMPORTHTML("https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Bestiary/Levels_1_to_10","table","1")

This doesn't include the images though. I also found this question was asked a couple years ago: Is there a way to import images from a Wiki table into a spreadsheet?
However I don't know how to apply to answers to the table I am using.

I don't think you want to import the entire page using import html.  I think there is a way to just link to the specific graphic instead and that should work.


You may try:
=let(Σ,importxml("https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Bestiary/Levels_1_to_10","//img/@srcset",),
 index(iferror(image("oldschool.runescape.wiki"&regexreplace(Σ,"(?:\s|\n)2x",)))))



This command ,IMPORTHTML, pulls the entire page into the cell, which is not what you want I am sure.
If you just want to import the images instead, use this command :
=IMAGE("URL")

And then you just change "URL" to the location of the specific image you want to embed into your sheet.

But I have to do that one at a time for each image in the whole table?

If you don't want to specify which images and rather it to be dynamic you have to figure out how to do that with the already existing answer here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71038495/is-there-a-way-to-import-images-from-a-wiki-table-into-a-spreadsheet

That's what I'm trying to do, I just don't understand it at all. I'm having a hard time figuring out what to change to have it apply to my situation.

Since someone already asked this question on how to do that, that link is the only place on Stack Overflow that this can be answered, so you might ask over there how to do that.  But unless you need to do this dynamically all the time, just doing it by hand would likely just take a few minutes.  Unless you are just trying to learn how to do that versus getting the results done, but again if thats the case, check that link and ask over there.
